# Adding to the registry in C++ win32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a batch file that has this line..

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\SomeName" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "/path/to/SomeName.json" /f
```

I want to do the same from a c++ code. I found the function `RegCreateKeyExA` and I am using it like this

```
    HKEY hKey;
    LPCSTR sk = "Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\SomeName";
    LONG openRes = RegCreateKeyExA(
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        sk,
        0,
        NULL,
        REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
        KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
        NULL,
        &hKey,
        NULL);
```

but how to add the data part? `/ve /t REG_SZ /d "/path/to/SomeName.json" /f`

UPDATE:
based on @Alan Britles comment I did the following:

```
    HKEY hKey;
    
    LONG openRes = RegCreateKeyExA(
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        "HKCU\\Software\\Google\\Chrome\\NativeMessagingHosts\\SomeName",
        0,
        NULL,
        REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
        KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
        NULL,
        &hKey,
        NULL);
    if (openRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        log+="Success creating key.";
    }
    else {
        log += "Error creating key.";
    }

    LPCSTR value = NULL;
    std::string temp = QString(data_path + "\\SomeName.json").toStdString();
    LPCSTR data = temp.c_str()+'\0';

    LONG setRes = RegSetValueExA(hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)data, strlen(data) + 1);

    if (setRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
       log+="Success writing to Registry.";
    }
    else {
        log += "Error writing to Registry.";
    }
```

I get success Writing but I don't see it added in the registry editor... What am I doing wrong?

Update #2:
I got rid of `HKCU` in the sub key..

```
LONG openRes = RegCreateKeyExA(
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        "Software\\Google\\Chrome\\NativeMessagingHosts\\SomeName",
        0,
        NULL,
        REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
        KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
        NULL,
        &hKey,
        NULL);
```

But I still get success returns and nothing added to the registry.. Is it a problem related to permissions? Or am I calling the wrong functions?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvaluea

Comment: Hint: Search in the docs how REG ADD processes its parameters. Then describe what operations are to be done in the registry. Finally code those operation using winapi functions.

Comment: Ok.. but what is the `LPCSTR lpSubKey` in my case? I want to pass the json file which has all the (key, value) pairs..

Comment: [What is the terminology for describing the various parts of the registry?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090204-00/?p=19263)

Comment: You know that a backslash in a string needs a double \ to escape it?
Seams that you have simply trouble with string constants and this is a x / y question.

Comment: I edited the question...I fixed what you all mentioned but it still not in the registry!

Comment: Get rid of the "HKCU" part in string. You are already specifying it as the first parameter.

Comment: As the comment above, The value you set is actually under the key:`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\HKCU\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\SomeName`

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson I got rid of the "HKCU"  and I get the same... success messages but nothing in the registry..

Comment: Did you close and reopen the registry to check for changes? I cannot reproduce this issue in win10 2004.